# a in-class class access the outer class's data member

Tags: c++

I was trying to do this,

```
class Outer {
public:
    struct inner_t {
        void foo()
        {
            printf("%d", _x);
        }
    };
    int _x;
};

int main()
{
    Outer o;
    o._x = 10;
}
```

The above can't compile with errors:

> error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Outer::_x’

But according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870002/888051), `inner_t` can indeed access `Outer::_x`, what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is: `inner_t` does not know an instance of `Outer` to read `_x` from.

If you had written (for example):

```
void foo(const Outer *o)
{
    printf("%d", o->_x);
}
```

Or if `_x` was a static member of `Outer`.
Then it should work (at least it will give no error).

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed access `_x` of object of type `Outer`. You try basically to access instance field in static fashion. Pass an instance of `Outer` and then use it.